# ¿Cómo poner una imagen como encabezado sin que salga pixelada, con HTML Y CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo el cuarpo de un email, y quiero poner un encabezado como imagen, el codigo lo tengo asi:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <img src="img/encabezado12.jpg" width="100%"  >
    <p style="font-family: Constantia, serif; font-size:17px; ">Con base al requerimiento </p>
    <img src="img/pie_pag.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Resulta ser que si quito el Width, la imagen sale correctamente, sin verse borrosa, pero si le dejo el width, sale borrosa o mas bien pixelada,  alguna sugerencia en que hacer? si le quito el width ya no seria responsive y esa es la idea.

Comment: Claro, porque si aumentas una imagen, pierde calidad. Por eso se ve borrosa cuando tienes el width puesto y cuando lo quitas, la imagen se ve nítida.

Comment: Si te refieres a que quieres ver los pixeles, quizás te ayude esto: https://css-tricks.com/keep-pixelated-images-pixelated-as-they-scale/

Answer (score 1):

Debido a que es imposible que quede perfecto por la relación de aspecto, algunas partes no quedarán visibles...pero es inevitable.

Lo que considero mejor para hacer es, que para que la imagen cubra todo, usar `backgroung-size: cover`. Para ello debes usar un `div` y no una `img`. Además usar las siguientes propiedades. Lo puedes hacer desde con `style` en el html o añades una clase y lo pones en el css.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```css
.fondo {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/630/380/) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 380px;
}

/* No hace falta añadirle width porque con el bacground-size de arriba ya cubre todo. El height lo puedes regular para la altura que desees. En este caso lo deje de la altura original de la foto */
```

```html
<div class="fondo">
```

Esta es una de las mejores formas de escalar la imagen sin que la deforme. Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar.